# Set up single authentication link to multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I didn't even know how the phrase the question properly on this one, but here is the scenario -

We have one domain with many many site collections for each of our customers. The customers each get their own link on login details that are unique to their site collection.

My question, is it possible to set up a universal link, that once the user has logged in, will redirect them to their individual site collection?

The end product would be one link we can send to all clients along with their login details. Once they've type in the login details they'll go to their site.

Hope that makes sense!

We're currently running 2010 Foundation, but changing to 2013 Foundation in the near future.

Comment: An HttpHandler might be what you're after. It could intercept the request, look at some value of the authenticating user (e.g. perform an LDAP lookup of a 'customer' attribute), then forward them off to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign can be achieved easily by SharePoint. You can store mapping for each user with their site collection in my sites or external system. Then you can write custom HTTP handler to redirect them to their site.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2010/08/04/deploying-an-asp-net-httphandler-to-sharepoint-2010/